# Can Netty get a notification of SSLEngine getting a close_notify

Tags: ssl, netty

I have a situation where my (non netty) client is closing the SSLSocket but not the underlying Socket. This does exactly what would be expected it sends a close_notify to the server, which replies with a close_notify.

However my server is Netty based, and uses SSLHandler, by adding a LoggingHandler() I can see it getting the close_notify, and responding with a close_notify. The problem is my upstream handlers get no notifications at all, as the underlying Socket is not closing so there is no disconnect. I specifically want the sockets to remain open.

What I need is to get a notification that the SSLHandler has shutdown, so I can remove the SLLHandler from the pipeline and continue communicating with normal TCP.

Is this possible in Netty?

As part of my investigations I tried closing the SSlHandler from the server/netty side, and that would work except Netty closes down the sslhandler before getting the clients close_notify (as per design and spec), the trouble is that any subsequent read of the underlying socket gets that close_notify as raw data as the SslHandler has shutdown. If possible I would rather not have to write a handler that duplicates the SslEngines job of reading SSL messages. I understand why SSlHandler does not wait for the clients close_notify reply, which is why I tried to do it from the client side where I have more control of the SSL sockets.

Comment: Seems the answer is no, I went over the source code and it appears that currently Netty does not detect the SSLEngine processing a close_notify, so you end up with a situation where the SSLEngine is in state CLOSED, but the upper layer does not know that. I will look to see what needs to be done to detect the CLOSED status. I think probably a Future could be attached to the SslHandler to allow a callback to be called if the SSLEngine closes.